# LDAP Query to find all the DLs to which particular user belongs to

Tags: ldap

We are using Spring LDAP and we are successfully able to find all the DLs from AD using Query `(&(objectCategory=Group)(proxyAddresses=*))`

We are also trying to find all the  DLs to which particular user belongs to, but we are not able to find it. We tried below queries.

1. `(&(objectCategory=Group) (member=CN=John Doe, CN=Users,OU=Unit1, DC=mydomain, DC=com))`
2. `(&(objectCategory=*) (sAMAccountName=xy12345))`

Spring LDAP snippet :

```
List results =  ldapTemplate.search("DC=mydomain, DC=com", "LDAP Query", new AttributesMapper() {
    ....
};
```